# Start timer at a variable time and not from beginning

Tags: javascript, timer

I am using this to have a timer in my app: https://gist.github.com/electricg/4372563.

Anyhow, I want to start my timer not from the beginning but from a variable value - "data". Data contains the number of milliseconds.

How do I go about it?

I have tried modifing x.startAt - which didn't give any error, but strange output.

Comment: *which didn't give any error, but strange output.* Try to elaborate a little more please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408191/timer-using-javascript have a look at this

Comment: `startAt` defined in `clsStopwatch` function scope, so you can't refer outside of that function and it's not property of `clsStopwatch` instances.

Comment: Simply add parameter to `var clsStopwatch = function(t)` and then `var startAt = t || 0;`

Comment: coder can only accept the answer from [@useruser221287](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2134555/user221287) :-D and vice versa ???

Comment: @user3110424 I have accepted answers from many different users.

Comment: @user3110424 and I upvote all answers to my quetions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `lapTime` property instead of `startAt`;

```
var lapTime = 10000; //milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this function

```
// Duration
this.time = function() {
     return lapTime + (startAt ? now() - startAt : 100); 
};
```

You have to change the initial value in this function.